# Doctrine MongoDB ODM

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm

I am learning Doctrine 2 ODM for MongoDB and have a straight forward question that i cant find an answer to in Doctrines docs or on google.

Say i have the following two documents in the same collection

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51c8a962f6d6ace76b374219"), 
"X" : 26, 
"Name" : "some name", 
"Level" : "Common"
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("51c8a9bef6d6ace76b37421a"), 
"Y" : 1, 
"Name" : "Other name", 
"Level" : "Common"
}
```

I know i can find all documents that have Level : Common using

```
$dm->getRepository('Search\Model')->findBy(array("Level" => "Common"));
```

But how can i find all documents where field type is "X" and not "Y"?
I know i could return all and filter it out but i should be able to query this right?
Because the fields types X and Y are different should they be in a separate collection?

I've also tried various queries using query builder as in the Doctrine docs but no luck.

I really want to be able to return all documents in that collection that are only "X".

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use negation operators here:

```
$dm->getRepository('Search\Model')->findBy(array("X" => 26, "Y" => array('$ne'=>1)));
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  what i'm really looking for is to find all documents with an X field and not Y's. Is there a wildcard i can use for the X value above....I guess the nearest SQL equivalent would be SELECT * from TABLE where Column=X

Comment: @sb12 You can use `$exists`, that will judge if that field actually exists in the document: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/

Comment: thanks for the replies. I would have thought something like this was quite common. Reason i allowed different fields in the documents was due to the schemaless nature of mongo and so assumed querying would be straight forward.  From the doctrine docs i cant find a way to return what i need. Is it best practice to return all docs in the collection and deal with the filtering in the application? I guess performance is not an issue as a cursor is returned instead of all the data? thanks for the help

Comment: @sb12 Not really because to deal with this client side you would have to pick out a tremendous amount of data, isn't `$exists` what your looking for?

Comment: It works fine, thanks. I need to consult the mongo docs as much as the doctrine ones :). Thanks for the help